# How to find the maximum value of a parameter [Omega] in a trigonometric function?

Tags: trigonometry

The form of the known trigonometric function is:

```
f[x_] := Sin[ω x + ϕ]
```

The known conditions are:

```
ω > 0, ϕ ∈ {0, 2 π}
```

One of the symmetry axes is:

```
x == -π/6
```

How can I find the maximum value of the parameter `ω` such that the function monotonically increases on the interval $(\pi, 4\pi/3)$?

```
ClearAll["`*"]
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[ω x + ϕ], {x, π, 4π/3}], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {ω, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Please clarify "find the maximum value of the parameter \[Omega] "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make an "Ansatz":

```
f[x_]= Sin[w x + off]
```

Now the first condition: x== -Pi/6 is a symmetry axis. This will be fulfilled if we choose -Pi/6 w +off == Pi/2.

The second condition: w is maximal so that f[x] is increasing in [Pi,4/3 Pi]: To better understand this we draw a plot where x==-Pi/6 is a symmetry axis:

```
Plot[Sin[x + 2/3 Pi], {x, -1/2 Pi, 4/3 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> Line[{{{Pi, -1}, {Pi, 1}}, {{4/3 Pi, -1}, {4/3 Pi, 1}}}]]
```

[image]

If we increase w the curve in [Pi,4/3 Pi] gets steeper. The highest value of w is reached when f[4/3Pi] is 1 and f[Pi] is still an the ascending slope. This gives an upper bond for w.

With these 2 conditions we may write the equations:

```
eq = {-w  Pi/6 + off == Pi/2, w  4/3 Pi + off == 2 Pi + 5/2 Pi};
sol = Solve[eq, {w, off}][[1]];
f[x_] = Sin[w x + off ] /. sol
```

[image]

We can plot this:

[image]

Therefore the maximal value of w is: 8/3

Answer (score 1):

Try to answer on my own：

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@{y == Sin[x]}, {x, -1, 4 π}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.01}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 ImageSize -> Full]

Reduce[{-π/6 ω + ϕ == k1 π + π/2, ω x + ϕ == k2 π + π/2, 
  0 < ω, 0 < ϕ < 2 π, k1 ∈ Integers, 
  k2 ∈ Integers}, x, ϕ]
(* Reduce::bdomv: Warning: ϕ is not a valid 
   domain specification. Assuming it is a 
   variable to eliminate. *)
(* (k1 | k2) ∈ 
  Integers && ((k1 <= -1 && -3 - 6 k1 < ω < 9 - 6 k1 && 
     x == (-6 k1 π + 6 k2 π - π ω)/(
      6 ω)) || (k1 == 0 && 0 < ω < 9 && 
     x == (6 k2 π - π ω)/(6 ω)) || (k1 == 1 && 
     0 < ω < 3 && x == (-6 π + 6 k2 π - π ω)/(6 ω))) *)

eq1 = -π/6 ω + ϕ == k π + π/2;
eq2 = ω x + ϕ == k π + π/2;
SubtractSides[eq1, eq2]
(* -((π ω)/6) - x ω == 0 *)

Reduce[-((π ω)/6) - x ω == k π, x] // Expand
(* (ω == 0 && k == 0) || (ω != 0 && x == -(π/6) - (k π)/ω) *)

Reduce[{-(π/6) + (k π)/ω <= π, -(π/6) + ((k + 1) π)/ω >= 
  (4 π)/3, ω > 0, 
  k ∈ Integers}, ω]
(* (k == 0 && 0 < ω <= 2/3) || (k == 1 && 
   6/7 <= ω <= 4/3) || (k == 2 && 
   12/7 <= ω <= 2) || (k == 3 && 18/7 <= ω <= 8/3) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Symmetry condition `Sin[om (-Pi/6+u) +phi]==Sin[om (-Pi/6+x)+phi]` is fullfilled for `phi-> (2k+1)Pi/2+om Pi/6` with `Element[k,Integers]`

```
sym=phi-> (2k+1)Pi/2+om Pi/6;

(Sin[om (-Pi/6 + u) + phi] == Sin[om (-Pi/6 - u) + phi] // 
TrigToExp) /. sym //Simplify[#, Element[k, Integers]] &
(*True*)
```

Function `Sin[om x +phi]` is mononton if `D[Sin[om x +phi],x]=om Cos[om x +phi]>=0` in the given range `Pi<= x<= 4Pi/3`

```
mon = om Cos[om x + phi] >= 0 /. sym;
(*om Cos[1/2 (1 + 2 k) \[Pi] + (om \[Pi])/6 + om x] >= 0*)
```

Last condition is simplified to

```
tmp=FullSimplify[mon /. Sin[k Pi + a_] -> TrigExpand[Sin[b + a]] /. b -> k Pi, {om > 0, Element[k, Integers]}];
rule = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {{Sin[k Pi], Cos[k Pi]}, {Sin[k Pi], Cos[k Pi]} // Simplify[#, Element[k, Integers]] &}]
monS = tmp /. Sin[k Pi + a_] -> TrigExpand[Sin[b + a]] /. b -> k Pi/.rule   
(*(-1)^k Sin[(om \[Pi])/6 + om x] <= 0*)
```

solution k odd:

```
RegionPlot[monS /. k -> 1, {x, \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]/3}, {om, 0, 5}, PlotLabel -> "k odd", FrameLabel -> {x, \[Omega]}]
```

[image]

solution k even:

```
RegionPlot[monS /. k -> 2, {x, \[Pi], 4 \[Pi]/3}, {om, 0, 5},PlotLabel -> "k even", FrameLabel -> {x, \[Omega]}]
```

[image]

As we can see the max value of `\[Omega]` isn't unique and depends on the aloowable parameter range.